# How to stop the page from running when I type localhost ip on Mac Ventura

Tags: apache, server, localhost, httpd.conf

On my Mac when I type my localhost's ip into google bar, it shows a page written 'It works!'. But when I type localhost, server doesn't connect, it shows nothing.

I want to disable the page that is shown. I don't want that page to be shown.

On the terminal I typed this command

```
sudo apachect1 -k stop
```

It says that `AH00558: httd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using My-macbook-name. local. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message httpd (no pid file) not running.`

Then I typed

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

It says `Unload failed: 5: Input/output error. Try running "launchctI bootout as root for richer errors.`

When I type

```
launchctl bootout
```

It shows me how to use this command.

When I type

```
map localhost -p 80
```

It says `PORT STATE SERVICE 80/tcp closed http`

---

I also checked brew services for httpd and apache and it shows that they aren't running

when I type

```
ps aux | grep httpd
```

It shows `10585   0,0  0,0 407962000    128 s000  R+   11:56PM   0:00.00 grep httpd`

Then I typed

```
sudo kill -9 10585
```

It says `no such process`

I also typed this command to see TCP connections

```
sudo Isof -i -n -P I grep TCP
```

It gives me the result that I pinned the photo below.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZFOU.png)

Can u tell me why I connect to my localhost's ip. And also can it happen any security problems on my Mac because of this issue?

I'II appreciate if someone can help me :)

Comment: We should back up a couple levels. When you say "localhost IP', you mean in a browser, you type something? Like "http://127.0.0.1/" (probably not that, but just to illustrate.